# Invalid multi level users navigating page PHP

Tags: php, mysql

My login page couldn't read on the multi level users. I have two types of users: UMD and CMD. Their location page will be different based on their level (CMD_home.php for CMD & UMD_home2.php for UMD). Currently when click login, both user navigate to UMD_home2.php page. Below are my codes, please assist to edit the code.

```
<?php

include "../setting/config.php";

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['login']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    //UMD,CMD
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM registered_accounts WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";

    if (count(fetchAll($query2)) > 0)
    { //this is to catch unknown error.
        foreach (fetchAll($query2) as $row)
        {
            if ($row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password)
            {
                $_SESSION['test'] = true;
                $level['level'] == "CMD";
                header('location:CMD_home.php');
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<script>alert('Wrong login details.')</script>";
            }
        }
    }

}

if (isset($_POST['login']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    //UMD,CMD
    $query3 = "SELECT * FROM registered_accounts WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";

    if (count(fetchAll($query2)) > 0)
    { //this is to catch unknown error.
        foreach (fetchAll($query2) as $row)
        {
            if ($row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password)
            {
                $_SESSION['test'] = true;
                $level['level'] == "UMD";
                header('location:UMD_home2.php');
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<script>alert('Wrong login details.')</script>";
            }
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Remove the second  isset($_POST['login'] ...
From the first query get the level from select query and redirect to the corresponding page

Comment: You always need to `exit` after a header or it will just carry on to the end of the page.

Comment: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)
 and don't store plain text passwords in your db

Comment: It works fine now after I follow Mr Tim's code and I've added $query_run=mysqli_query($conn, $query2); $level = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run); under the query line. But the alert message doesn't display if I key in invalid username & pass, as well click login without key in anything.. Before this it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is really easy. There is no if statments arround the `$level['level'] == "CMD";` and `$level['level'] == "UMD";`

Try this:

```php
<?php
include "../setting/config.php";

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

    if (!isset($_POST['username']) || !isset($_POST['password'])){
        exit;
    }

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    //UMD,CMD

    $sql = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM registered_accounts WHERE username = :name AND password = :password');

    $sql->execute([ 'name' => $username , 'password' => $password]);

    if (count($sql) > 0) { //this is to catch unknown error.
        foreach ($sql as $row) {
            if ($row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password) {
                $_SESSION['test'] = true;
                if($level['level'] == "CMD"){
                    header('location:CMD_home.php');
                    exit;
                }else if($level['level'] == "UMD"){
                    header('location:UMD_home2.php');
                    exit;
                }
            }else{
                alert();
            }
        }
    }else {
        alert();
    }
    function alert(){
        echo "<script>alert('Wrong login details.')</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Undefined variable: level in ...\test.php and Trying to access array offset on value of type null in  ...\test.php on line 39 which is in code if($level['level'] == "CMD"){

Comment: It means that you havn't set the `$level['level']` variable

Comment: Where are the `levels` stored?

Comment: It works fine now. I've added $query_run=mysqli_query($conn, $query2); $level = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run); under the query line.

Comment: But the alert message doesn't display if I key in invalid username & pass, as well click login without key in anything.. Before this it works...

Comment: After another look i think the issue is that you alert is at a wrong location. I eddited my answer so it;s at the correct location. I also added protection for `injection` and added `exit; tags`

Comment: This works perfect !.. Thank you so much for your time @Tim587